# Py2exe - Executable Icon does not show

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to build binaries for an application written in Python with Py2exe. This is my example setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows = [{ "script": "app.py", "icon_resources": [(1, "appicon.ico")]}],
    options = {
        "py2exe" : {
            "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]
        }
    }
)
```

While the .exe is compiled and works correctly the icon is not shown. When opening the .exe with Resource Hacker I can see that the icon is there, but saved in "0" instead of "1". When I save the icon manually into the right slot it works.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I use gui2exe so that i don't need to write setup.py manually and I never had a problem with icon. You do not need to install guy2exe. just download and execute as python script by double clicking. It's easy to use.